# What do you call a person who handles contractual paperwork?

Tags: definition

As an administrative assistant, one of the jobs I had to perform was keeping track of all contractual employees, writing their schedules, and ensuring that they got their paychecks.
That was not my job; Administrative Assistant was my job. However, it is something that my boss decided I could do instead of him.
In updating my resume, I wanted to write exactly what such a position would be called.

Comment: I suggest you write your actual job title, and then summarise the particular duties under headings such as "Contracts administration" and "Payroll clerk". You can't say you were the Contracts Manager if you weren't, but you can spell out what you did. This was your *experience* or *role*, not your job.

Comment: I agree with @weather-vane. "Administrative assistant" is the correct job title, and your duties included keeping track of all... (as you describe).